# Convergence to zero of a specific infinite product

Tags: infinite-product

[image]

Maybe less ambitious but I would be happy to prove the following. I have tried but without success.

Thanks for any help

Comment: After some work I can show that $ \prod (1 - (1-p_n)^n)$    behaves exactly as $ \prod (1 - e^{-np_n})$ . Now the answer to my previous question is a simple corollary. Now, giving the decreasing sequence  $0 < p_n <= 1$   the next and probably more challenging question is to determine the right behaviour of the sequence   $np_n$ in order to have the product $\prod (1 - (1-p_n)^n)$    being 0 or positive. 

The conjecture is the following:  Let   $p_n = a log(n)/n$    with a real,  $ 0 \le a$   then the product is not nul for 1 < a  and nul for  0<= a <=1

Counterexamples? Thank a lot

Answer (score 0):

Hint: 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (1-1/n)^n = 1/e$$
What does this tell you about the limit of $(1-1/n)^{8n+4}$?

Comment: Ho! yes of course, thank you Robert. Then after a certain point my product behaves like an infinite power of (1-1/e) and then converging to 0.

Looking further , I have done numerical computations that seems to show that also the following product is zero:

$$\prod (1 - (1-p_n)^{8n+4})  \ with \ p_n= 1/(nlog(n))$$

But if I am not wrong, the above argument cannot be applied.

Comment: In this case $1 - (1 - p_n)^{8n+4} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$, so of course the product goes to $0$.

Comment: More generally I am interested for which sequences of $p_n$ the infinite product converges to zero and for which it converges to a positive value. To this end, using the Euler formula that you mentioned above for $e$ if I write $ p_n  $ $ as $n p_n/n $  $ can  I  estimate  the  previous  product  with$  \prod (1 - e^{-np_n}) $ in the sense that both converges simultaneously to zero or to a positive value?